# How to create sql log's for selected table's in a database in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, logging, phpmyadmin

**Case scenario** :

Database : sample_db

```
Table's : table_1 ,table_2 , table_3 , table_4
```

All the table's has column `row_id`

I want to create sql queries log if there is any row insert/update/delete for `row_id = 'some_value'` for `table_1` and `table_3` for a `sample_db`

`Edits` :

```
Sample Example :
```

Let say there is a database school_db , which has following tables:

```
a.school. [school_id,school_name] 
b.class. [school_id,class_id,class_name]
c.section. [school_id,class_id,section_id,section_name]
d.marks. [school_id,student_id,marks]
e.exams. [school_id,class_id,exam_id,exam_name]
```

Now for a particular school's , let's say 'ABC school' which has school_id = 10 .

```
I want to log all the sql queries that are run for 'ABC school' for tables school,marks and exams.
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/audit-log-plugin.html

Comment: i think (if i understand what you whant) that u can try with a trigger

Comment: I think your options are to use triggers, write insert queries near every insert,update,delete query in PHP or use the sql-query log and filter it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use triggers in the database.

Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER log_update AFTER UPDATE ON table_1
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
         IF NEW.row_id in ('some_value','some_other_value') THEN
             INSERT INTO log .....;
         END IF;
     END;
```

You replace the dots by somethign you want to insert into the log.
Repeat this for table_3.

Also repeat this to replace UPDATE with DELETE.

You could use this to trigger on INSERT, but I don't see the point since row_id doesn't exist yet (assuming it's unique).

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Tracking" and choose table for tracking and events for table, which are you want racking. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: AFAIK tracking is per default not available on a MySQL server.

Comment: And If I interpret the [PHPMyAdmin documentation](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Change_tracking) correctly it only tracks changes made with PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

In your event log table, do you need to know also who insert, update, delete or made changes in another table ?